# cipher/decipher the message between Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, cryptography

I have 2 programs: 1st - is in Java, 2nd - is in C#.

I need to exchange data between them safely. I need to cipher data in Java, and decipher in C#.

Please help me. I don't need 3rd party libraries. Alternatively, please give me the best 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 0):

[BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) has encryption implementations in both Java and C#; I believe they should play well together.